# cannot run flutter commands without device connected

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea

I have bought a Mac ( previously using windows ) and setting it up with IntelliJ and all flutter and dart plugins. When I run flutter commands ( eg: functions, class ) as part of the curriculum my IntelliJ IDE keeps saying no device connected. Do I need a Virtual device ( iOS or android ) connected to IDE for just trying out commands? if then it's time taking as every time I click on Run, it is doing a hot reload which is unnecessary. Please advise

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to run a flutter project you will need a device or an emulator connected. If you just want to run some lines of code you can run the dart file.  Flutter is for mobile development whereas dart is the language which flutter uses.

Comment: can you be more specific (sorry am a newbie to flutter). I have tried to create a new project with dart, choosing simple command line and this time the Run button is greyed out.   How can I run dart commands and see the outputs in Run console in IntelliJ IDE.

Comment: The run button is for flutter projects. You can run your dart file from the command line. Before asking questions on Stack Overflow you should do some basic research and check the docs. From the dart Docs. https://dart.dev/tutorials/server/cmdline